How do i get Recently Viewed id Listview in code, more appropriate question can we get it?
Hey is it possible to get the standard list view 'Recently Viewed' List view for leads, Accounts or contacts in code. If yes how?
SELECT Id, Name, LastViewedDate,Email,NameOrAlias,  RecordType.SobjectType FROM RecentlyViewed - gives the user recently viewed records but this does not answer regarding listviews.
SELECT Id, Name,DeveloperName FROM ListView WHERE SobjectType = 'Lead' does not give the required one as well.

This question is similar to: How to get Recent View Records?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can access the standard "Recently Viewed" list view for Leads, Accounts, or Contacts using the Salesforce User Interface API. The special list view API name for the "Recently Viewed" list is __Recent.
Mentioned in document:

To get record data for the most recently used (MRU) list view for
accounts, use the special __Recent list view API name.
GET /services/data/v62.0/ui-api/list-records/Account/__Recent

Example code:
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v61.0/ui-api/list-info/Account/__Recent');
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());

Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse res = http.send(req);

if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
   System.debug('Response: ' + res.getBody());
} else {
   System.debug('Error: ' + res.getStatusCode() + ' ' + res.getStatus());
}

Also, see the Most Recently Used List View Supported Objects.

Thanks Tushar Jadav
